# Moving /var (partition) to another disk as a whole

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

Currently, */var* has its own partition on *disk A*:

[image]

I would like to move it as a whole (no file copying whatsoever) to another disk, *disk B*, filling all its free space (~1Tb). Then I would like to extend *Partition 1* on the *disk A* with all the space currently allocated for *Partition 2 (Extended)*.

**Q.** How do I do it either via Terminal or using GUI-assisted software?

Comment: You can `mv` (move) files on the same disk/partition (the directory entry itself is moved, data (*inodes*) isn't), but it'll really can't be done to a different disk/partition (including a different partition on the same physical drive).  If by move you mean the directory entry only, it cannot be done. To move (via copy of data/inodes) it can be done when unmounted, where a *live* system maybe easiest.

Comment: "disk"? I would never ever separate system directories over more than 1 disk. Do you know what happens if your 2nd disk does not boot up quick enough? If this is about space for MYSQL databases you are better off moving your database to that 2nd disc. Same for cups and log files in /var/. ALL of them have settings that allow altering the directories used.

Comment: @Rinzwind Sounds reasonable. Will look into it.